# Can't add an answer to question Don't google “google” on Programming Puzzles & Code Golf

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, protected-questions, privileges

I just writed an answer for [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/58891/45600) on my computer. I was to post my answer and just found there isn't any "add another answer" button. It only say that it required 10 reputations to answer... But I have got 101 for being trusted on other stackoverflow site.

What is wrong here? How can I post my answer?

Comment: You got 100 rep from the association bonus, whcih doesn't count as the rep for protected questions. You have to earn 10 rep on that site in order to post on protected questions. [Read this MSE post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170937/why-is-association-bonus-ignored-when-trying-to-answer-a-protected-question) and [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-question).

Comment: Ok, thanks. This notions is weird, you have 101 reputions but you don't really do. Reputions point should be reputation point. Make it simpler not more complex... Why do simple when we can do complex they say. Thanks a lot. You should post this as an answer

Answer (score 14):

This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) because you have to earn 10 rep on the site, in order to answer a protected question. The 100 rep association bonus doesn't apply towards the rep needed.

[From this MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-question)

> ### Who can answer a protected question?
>
> Users with 10 or more reputation can answer a protected question. **However, the +100 account association bonus is ignored for this check**, so you must have earned 10 or more reputation on that specific site to answer a protected question.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! :D